# Check the Comment in Reply or Normal State

Tags: comments

I'm currently working with custom comment meta, and I have some custom additional field such as rating etc, when user write a comment ( not comment reply ) I want to show the rating field, but when it's on reply comment state I want to remove this field.

Is there a build in conditional function to check whether it's in a reply state or not? or any other way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3):

Check for the `comment_parent`:

```
if( '0' != $comment->comment_parent ){
    // this is a reply
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @diggy, I'm using comment_form() function to output the comment in the theme, so how can I do this using comment hook?

Comment: `comment_form` displays the form, I assume you want to customize comments, and not the form? Check for `wp_list_comments` to find out what callback function is used to display comments, e.g. in twentytwelve the callback is `twentytwelve_comment`, which is located in functions.php. Edit the callback function to incorporate the rating data, e.g. `<?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_parent ) : ?>RATING STUFF GOES HERE<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: I just made it work using global $comment in the comment_form_after_fields action, one thing not going well is when I open the link to reply manually it work eq.(http://localhost/wp/?p=123&replytocom=17#respond) , but not while using comment-reply.js when the comment is just move to another place but not removing the field. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is quite old, but I just solved this problem today with a JQuery-based approach.

```
jQuery( function() {
  jQuery("#commentform").attr("data-parsly-validate", " ");

  jQuery("#commentform").parsley();

  jQuery(".comment-meta-header .comment-reply-link").click(function(){
    jQuery("#commentform .comment-form-area, #commentform .comment-form-type").hide();
    jQuery("#starling-comment-area, #starling-comment-type").removeAttr("required");
  });

  jQuery("#cancel-comment-reply-link").click(function(){
    jQuery("#commentform .comment-form-area, #commentform .comment-form-type").show();
    jQuery("#starling-comment-area, #starling-comment-type").attr("required", " ");
  });
});
```

Basically I have click handlers for when the "Reply" or "Cancel" links are clicked, and I handle form validation with Javascript (using Parsley, in this case).

For server-side validation you can use diggy's solution.